# UserRoles property NULL for Core Identity User record

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I have a custom implementation of Core Identity Users, Roles and UserRoles. The following code is not working for me:

```
var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
if (user != null)
{
    if (_passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, password) != PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid password");
    }

    if (!await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
    {
        return BadRequest("Not a Admin");
    }
}
```

When looking at the user object, i see UserRoles property as null:
[image]

My Identity models are as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Accountgroups = new HashSet<Accountgroups>();
        Balances = new HashSet<Balances>();
        Payouts = new HashSet<Payouts>();
        Useralerts = new HashSet<Useralerts>();
        Userlogs = new HashSet<Userlogs>();
        Usersettings = new HashSet<Usersettings>();
        Userinvites = new HashSet<Userinvites>();
        Withdrawals = new HashSet<Withdrawals>();
    }

    public long LegacyUserId { get; set; }
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Timezone { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string AccountToken { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Activated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserLogin> Logins { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserToken> Tokens { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public virtual Accounts Account { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Accountgroups> Accountgroups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Balances> Balances { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Payouts> Payouts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Useralerts> Useralerts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Userlogs> Userlogs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Userinvites> Userinvites { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Usersettings> Usersettings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Withdrawals> Withdrawals { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }

}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<long>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<long>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserToken : IdentityUserToken<long>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRoleClaim> RoleClaims { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<long>
{
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

My Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextPool<dbContext>(
        options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection"),
            mysqlOptions =>
            {
                mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 14), ServerType.MySql);
            }
    ));

    services.AddDbContextPool<loggerContext>(
        options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection_Logger"),
            mysqlOptions =>
            {
                mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 14), ServerType.MySql);
            }
    ));

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();

    //Initialize Identity
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(config =>
    {
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        config.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        config.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        config.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        config.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    })
    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<dbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    //Authentication Configuration
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("TokenRequired", policy => policy.RequireClaim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
        options.AddPolicy("CloudUIAdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("IsCloudUIAdmin"));
        options.AddPolicy("AdminViewAs", policy => policy.RequireClaim("IsViewingAs"));
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        //MVC cookie authentication
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/login";
        options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
        options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
    });

    services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Shared"))
            .SetApplicationName("TheApp");

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    //Inject Identity configuration settings 
    services.Configure<IdentityConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("Identity"));

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
}
```

I've also attempted adding:

```
.AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser, 
                        ApplicationRole, 
                        dbContext, 
                        long, 
                        ApplicationUserClaim, 
                        ApplicationUserRole, 
                        ApplicationUserLogin, 
                        ApplicationUserToken, 
                        ApplicationRoleClaim>>()
.AddRoleStore<RoleStore<ApplicationRole, dbContext, long, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationRoleClaim>>();
```

and

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>>();
```

and

```
.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>()
```

Nothing seems to fill the user record with their roles.

I have done some searching on this and have found the following:
https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1361#issuecomment-348863959
https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813#issuecomment-420066501

Nothing seems to be changing my situation. Additionally i am able to create roles and assign user to roles just fine.

Am i missing something here to fill the users roles?

Answer (score 2):

Relationships are not automatically loaded. You must either eagerly, explicitly or lazy load them. Eager loading would be using `Include`, but you cannot do that via `UserManager<TUser>`. However, you can just use your context instead:

```
var user = await _context.Users.Include(x => x.UserRoles).SingleOrDefault(x => x.NormalizedUserName == userName.ToUpper());
```

That's admittedly not the most ideal way, but it's the only way to do this in a single query.

Explicit loading will issue an additional query, but you can keep using `UserManager<TUser>`.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
if (user != null)
{
    await _context.Entry(user).Collection(x => x.UserRoles).LoadAsync();
    ...
}
```

Finally, you can lazy load, which is what you're probably *trying* to do here, since you made all these properties `virtual`. Lazy-loading is still going to require an extra query (or more, ref: N+1 queries). It's similar to explicit loading, except that call to `LoadAsync` is basically in the custom getter on the proxy class EF adds, so you don't need to call it explicitly. In general, lazy-loading is frowned upon and should be avoided if at all possible. It is far too easy to end up thrashing your database with hundreds or even thousands of queries for what looks like a simple operation.

Regardless, if you do intend to go the lazy loading route, you have to actually enable it, which is done by calling `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` when you define your context:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<dbContext>(options => options
    .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection"), mysqlOptions =>
    {
        mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 14), ServerType.MySql);
    })
    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I now have: _context.Entry(user).Collection(x => x.UserRoles).Load();
if (!_userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin").GetAwaiter().GetResult())
{
    return BadRequest("Not a Admin");
}

Roles seems to be in the user record now, however IsInRoleAsync still returns a false. Should i not use _userManager?

Comment: If that's returning false, then the user literally isn't in that role. Simple as that. There's nothing complex about that method. You'll need to determine where your data is off. On a side not, what is your resistance to using async? ASP.NET Core is async top to bottom, and so is EF Core. In fact, the sync methods of EF Core merely block on the async versions. Embrace async/await.